# Reactjs update context from children component

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, createcontext

Starting with **ReactJS** and **NextJS**

I have the following Layout component and using context to set values from the children component

```
export interface AuthContextModel {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    showSignup: boolean;
}

export const AuthContext = createContext(null);

export const AuthLayout = ({children}) => {

    const [authContext, setAuthContext] = useState<AuthContextModel>();

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Authentication</title>
                <HeadComponent/>
            </Head>

            <AuthContext.Provider value={setAuthContext}>

                <h4>{authContext?.title}</h4>
                <p className="text-muted mb-4">Sign in to continue to Chatvia.</p>
                {children}

            </AuthContext.Provider>
        </>
    )
}
```

And the `Login` page extends the Layout

```
export default function Login(props) {
    const setAuthContext = useContext(AuthContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        setAuthContext({
            title: 'Sign In'
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <AuthLayout>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                ...

            </form>
        </AuthLayout>
    )
}
```

But the `setAuthContext` in the `Login` function is giving the following error

```
TypeError: setAuthContext is not a function
```

**How can I update the context variable from the children component?**

Answer (score 0):

When you mount the `Login`, that component is not a child of `AuthLayout`. As a result, `Login` will not gain access to `AuthContext`.

If you wanted `Login` to have access to `AuthContext`, it would need to be mounted something like this:

```js
<AuthLayout>
  <Login />
</AuthLayout>
```

Right now, you're mounting it like this:

```js
<AuthLayout>
  {/* Something else */}
</AuthLayout>
<Login />
```

The consumer (`Login`) is not a child of the provider (`AuthLayout`), so the consumer currently can't get anything from that context unless it is a child of the provider.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: `AuthLayout` is a wrapper function and the `Login` is rendered inside the AuthLayout using `{children}`. Initially it is not sure the which page to render, the `{children}` will dynamically load the page content. How can I put `<Login/>` in the AuthLayout because it could be SignUp or ForgotPassword, etc wrapped in AuthLayout?

Comment: `Login` is not child of `AuthLayout` - The rendered contents of `Login` _are_ children of `AuthLayout`, but the `Login` component itself is not. `Login` must be a direct child of `AuthLayout` to access any context that it exposed. See the pseudo code I wrote in my original answer for what I mean.

Comment: So as I want to change the title and description content on the Layout page to the page loaded, similar to `Login` there will be `Signup` and `ForgotPassword` components as well. So you mean that instead of using `{children}` in the `AuthLayout`, I should use `<AuthLayout><Login/><Signup/><ForgotPassword/></AuthLayout>`? Will, not it load all the pages altogether?

Comment: The last bit of code is what you need. In order for `Login` to access the context provided by `AuthLayout`, it must be mounted as a child of `AuthLayout`. In your original answer, `Login` is mounting `AuthLayout`, but that does not grant `Login` access to its context. `Login` must be a child of `AuthLayout` in order to access its context.